# google maps using viewpager(in a tab) and getMapAsync()

Tags: android, google-maps

i want to put google maps in a tab using viewPager ,thus viewPager uses fragments, i found multiple solutions that use the deprecated getMap, so android studio wouldn't even compile it, is there any up to date solution to get the map with viewPager ?

Comment: Can you post your error logs and code snippet?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In onCreateView in the mapsActivity.java that extends android.support.v4.app.Fragment and implements OnMapReadyCallback :

```
View rootView =inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_maps, container, false);
```

Obtain the SupportMapFragment and get notified when the map is ready to be used.

```
SupportMapFragment mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getChildFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map);   

    mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);
```